# QDbus signals not working (delivery is suspended)

Tags: c++, qt, cmake, signals, dbus

For my project, i need to have to use DBus with signals. For this i try to convert the the example program available at [D-Bus Remote Controlled Car Example](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtdbus-remotecontrolledcar-example.html) to run on linux ARM A7 processor (Qt 5.12.8 used).
I have realize the following steps:

1. Replace all HMI references by text outputs and symplify programs.
2. Migrate the project to use CMake at the place of qmake (Cmake > 3.0 used in final project)

CMakeLists.txt in car folder:

```cmake
set(QT_LIBS Qt5::Core Qt5::DBus)

add_custom_command(OUTPUT ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/car_adaptor.h ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/car_adaptor.cpp
  DEPENDS ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/car.xml
  COMMENT "Generate adaptors files for Dbus service"
  COMMAND /opt/dip/2.7-warrior+snapshot/sysroots/x86_64-dipsdk-linux/usr/bin/qdbusxml2cpp -a car_adaptor.h: ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/car.xml
  COMMAND /opt/dip/2.7-warrior+snapshot/sysroots/x86_64-dipsdk-linux/usr/bin/qdbusxml2cpp -i car_adaptor.h -a :car_adaptor.cpp ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/car.xml
  WORKING_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}
)

add_executable (car 
  main.cpp 
  car.cpp
  car_adaptor.cpp
)

set_target_properties(car PROPERTIES AUTOMOC TRUE)
target_link_libraries(car ${QT_LIBS})
```

CMakeLists.txt in controller folder:

```cmake
set(QT_LIBS Qt5::Core Qt5::DBus)

add_custom_command(OUTPUT ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/car_interface.h ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/car_interface.cpp
  DEPENDS ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/car.xml
  COMMENT "Generate interface files for Dbus service"
  COMMAND /opt/dip/2.7-warrior+snapshot/sysroots/x86_64-dipsdk-linux/usr/bin/qdbusxml2cpp -p car_interface.h: ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/car.xml
  COMMAND /opt/dip/2.7-warrior+snapshot/sysroots/x86_64-dipsdk-linux/usr/bin/qdbusxml2cpp -i car_interface.h -p :car_interface.cpp ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/car.xml
  WORKING_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}
)

add_executable (controller 
  main.cpp 
  controller.cpp
  car_interface.cpp
) 

set_target_properties(controller PROPERTIES AUTOMOC TRUE)
target_link_libraries(controller ${QT_LIBS})
```

### Problem description

My problem is the following: with these changes, the Dbus signals seem be emited by *car* app but no received by *controller* app.
I have try to understand the origin of problem with DBus debug mode (***QDBUS_DEBUG=1***) but not understand why all signals have the following return: *QDBusConnectionPrivate(0x75d006d0) delivery is suspended*
I probably miss one thing but i can't see what.

Test output:

```
export QDBUS_DEBUG=1
eval `dbus-launch --auto-syntax`
root@rzn1-embd:/tmp# ./car &
[1] 1391
root@rzn1-embd:/tmp# QDBusConnectionPrivate(0x75d006d0) : connected successfully
QDBusConnectionPrivate(0x75d006d0) got message (signal): QDBusMessage(type=Signal, service="org.freedesktop.DBus", path="/org/freedesktop/DBus", interface="org.freedesktop.DBus", member="NameAcquired", signature="s", contents=(":1.0") )
QDBusConnectionPrivate(0x75d006d0) sending message: QDBusMessage(type=MethodCall, service="org.freedesktop.DBus", path="/org/freedesktop/DBus", interface="org.freedesktop.DBus", member="RequestName", signature="", contents=("org.example.CarExample", 4) )
QDBusConnectionPrivate(0x75d006d0) delivery is suspended
QDBusConnectionPrivate(0x75d006d0) got message (signal): QDBusMessage(type=Signal, service="org.freedesktop.DBus", path="/org/freedesktop/DBus", interface="org.freedesktop.DBus", member="NameAcquired", signature="s", contents=("org.example.CarExample") )
QDBusConnectionPrivate(0x75d006d0) delivery is suspended
QDBusConnectionPrivate(0x75d006d0) got message reply: QDBusMessage(type=MethodReturn, service="org.freedesktop.DBus", signature="u", contents=(1) )
QDBusConnectionPrivate(0x75d006d0) dequeueing message QDBusMessage(type=Signal, service="org.freedesktop.DBus", path="/org/freedesktop/DBus", interface="org.freedesktop.DBus", member="NameAcquired", signature="s", contents=(":1.0") )
QDBusConnectionPrivate(0x75d006d0) dequeueing message QDBusMessage(type=Signal, service="org.freedesktop.DBus", path="/org/freedesktop/DBus", interface="org.freedesktop.DBus", member="NameAcquired", signature="s", contents=("org.example.CarExample") )
root@rzn1-embd:/tmp# ./controller
QDBusConnectionPrivate(0x75d006d0) : connected successfully
QDBusConnectionPrivate(0x75d006d0) got message (signal): QDBusMessage(type=Signal, service="org.freedesktop.DBus", path="/org/freedesktop/DBus", interface="org.freedesktop.DBus", member="NameAcquired", signature="s", contents=(":1.1") )
QDBusConnectionPrivate(0x75d006d0) delivery is suspended
QDBusConnectionPrivate(0x75d006d0) Adding rule: "type='signal',sender='org.freedesktop.DBus',interface='org.freedesktop.DBus',member='NameOwnerChanged',arg0='org.example.CarExample'"
QDBusConnectionPrivate(0x75d006d0) sending message: QDBusMessage(type=MethodCall, service="org.freedesktop.DBus", path="/org/freedesktop/DBus", interface="org.freedesktop.DBus", member="GetNameOwner", signature="", contents=("org.example.CarExample") )
QDBusConnectionPrivate(0x75d006d0) got message reply: QDBusMessage(type=MethodReturn, service="org.freedesktop.DBus", signature="s", contents=(":1.0") )
QDBusConnectionPrivate(0x75d006d0) Adding rule: "type='signal',sender='org.example.CarExample',path='/Car',interface='org.example.Examples.CarInterface',member='crashed'"
QDBusConnectionPrivate(0x75d006d0) sending message: QDBusMessage(type=MethodCall, service="org.freedesktop.DBus", path="/org/freedesktop/DBus", interface="org.freedesktop.DBus", member="GetNameOwner", signature="", contents=("org.example.CarExample") )
QDBusConnectionPrivate(0x75d006d0) got message reply: QDBusMessage(type=MethodReturn, service="org.freedesktop.DBus", signature="s", contents=(":1.0") )
QDBusConnectionPrivate(0x75d006d0) Watching service "org.example.CarExample" for owner changes (current owner: ":1.0" )

Menu:
        - Q: quitter
        - 1: Accelerate
        - 2: Decelerate
1
QDBusConnectionPrivate(0x75d006d0) sending message: QDBusMessage(type=MethodCall, service="org.example.CarExample", path="/Car", interface="org.example.Examples.CarInterface", member="accelerate", signature="", contents=() )
QDBusConnectionPrivate(0x75d006d0) got message (signal): QDBusMessage(type=MethodCall, service=":1.1", path="/Car", interface="org.example.Examples.CarInterface", member="accelerate", signature="", contents=() )
Speed:  1
QDBusConnectionPrivate(0x75d006d0) Automatically sending reply: ()
QDBusConnectionPrivate(0x75d006d0) sending message (no reply): QDBusMessage(type=MethodReturn, service="", signature="", contents=() )
QDBusConnectionPrivate(0x75d006d0) got message reply: QDBusMessage(type=MethodReturn, service=":1.0", signature="", contents=() )
QThread(ptr=0x76f0d370, name=QDBusConnectionManager) emitting signal at "/Car"
QDBusConnectionPrivate(0x75d006d0) got message (signal): QDBusMessage(type=Signal, service=":1.0", path="/Car", interface="org.example.Examples.CarInterface", member="crashed", signature="", contents=() )
QDBusConnectionPrivate(0x75d006d0) delivery is suspended
```

### Modified sources files:

car.h

```cpp
#ifndef CAR_H
#define CAR_H

#include <QObject>

class Car : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    Car();

public Q_SLOTS:
    void accelerate();
    void decelerate();

Q_SIGNALS:
    void crashed();

private:
    int speed;       // delta movement along the body axis
};

#endif // CAR_H
```

car.cpp

```cpp
#include "car.h"
#include <QDebug>

Car::Car() : speed(0) {}

void Car::accelerate() {
  if (speed < 10) 
    ++speed; 
  qInfo() << "Speed: " << speed << endl;
  if (speed > 0) 
    emit crashed(); 
}

void Car::decelerate() {
  if (speed > -10) 
    --speed;
  qInfo() << "Speed: " << speed << endl;
}
```

car/main.cpp

```cpp
#include "car.h"
#include "car_adaptor.h"
#include <QCoreApplication>
#include <QtDBus/QDBusConnection>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  QCoreApplication app(argc, argv);

  Car *car = new Car();
  new CarInterfaceAdaptor(car);
  QDBusConnection connection = QDBusConnection::sessionBus();
  connection.registerObject("/Car", car);
  connection.registerService("org.example.CarExample");
  return app.exec();
}
```

controller/main.cpp

```cpp
#include <QtDBus>
#include <QCoreApplication>
#include "controller.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  QCoreApplication app(argc, argv);
  Controller       controller;
  controller.start();
  return app.exec();
}
```

controller.h

```cpp
#ifndef CONTROLLER_H
#define CONTROLLER_H

#include "car_interface.h"
#include <QObject>

class Controller : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    Controller(QObject *parent = 0);
    void start();

private slots:
    void on_accelerate_clicked();
    void on_decelerate_clicked();
    void onCrashed();

private:
    org::example::Examples::CarInterface *car;
    void displayMenu();
};
#endif
```

controller.cpp

```cpp
#include "controller.h"
#include "car_interface.h"
#include <QDebug>

Controller::Controller(QObject *parent) : QObject(parent) {
  car = new org::example::Examples::CarInterface(
      "org.example.CarExample", "/Car", QDBusConnection::sessionBus(), this);
  connect(car, SIGNAL(crashed()), this, SLOT(onCrashed()));
}

void Controller::start() {
  char key = 0;
  displayMenu();
  while (key != 'Q') {
    key = getchar();
    switch (key) {
      case '1': on_accelerate_clicked(); break;
      case '2': on_decelerate_clicked(); break;
      case 'Q': exit(1); break;
    }
  }
}

void Controller::on_accelerate_clicked() { car->accelerate(); }

void Controller::on_decelerate_clicked() { car->decelerate(); }

void Controller::onCrashed() { qInfo() << "Controller: crashed"; }

void Controller::displayMenu() {
  qInfo() << "\r\nMenu:";
  qInfo() << "\t- Q: quitter";
  qInfo() << "\t- 1: Accelerate";
  qInfo() << "\t- 2: Decelerate";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Within the controller's `main()` function, execution never proceeds past `controller.start()` as this method contains the `while` loop that continuously polls the keyboard input, and it immediately exits if "Q" is pressed.

Therefore, you never reach `app.exec()` which runs the Qt event loop, and only within the event loop DBus signals are being received and processed.

You should switch to treat the keyboard presses event based. Alternatively, if you want to keep the `while` loop, you should modify it such that at least `QCoreApplication::processEvents()` (see its documentation) is being called frequently.